# Sample MTOM using Webservice not WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, web-services

I'm trying to implement a sample based on MTOM using Web Service

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528822.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529275.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529330.aspx

but stopping at wse3 editor not available in VS2013.
Wondering if I get a sample winforms application using MTOM with webservice instead of wcf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a way to integrate WSE3 settings in Visual Studio 2013 from [here](http://digantakumar.com/2010/06/04/wse-3-in-visual-studio-2008-and-2010/)